# How to sync playback control of Record and Reaper, without ReWire?

Tags: midi, reaper, playback, sync

Is there a way to transmit the "play/stop/record/loop" commands to both DAWs so that they play in sync?

Because of Record's lack of MIDI-Out support AND not being able to take incoming audio from external sources while in ReWire mode, I'm trying to work my way around it by feeding Reaper's output-channels into some of Record's input-channels (via Soundflower). It's not very practical, but I will have to write MIDI clips in Reaper (for VST instruments) and then MIDI clips in Record (for Record & Reason devices).

But now comes yet another issue, how can I sync both together? Does it require an external hardware MIDI-clock of some kind?

Answer (score 3):

If both Record and Reaper support MIDI sync from an external source, you can use virtual ports with [MIDI Yoke](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/myoke.htm) (or similar), and then a separate application (such as [MIDIOX](http://www.midiox.com/)) to send the play/stop parts.

This isn't Rewire though, so the loop start and end points won't work.

Comment: I voted this answer up because it's correct, but it's going to be a pain.